# Preventing safari from opening Preview for images

Tags: safari

Every time I download an image from a site, using Safari, as soon as the images finish download, it opens Preview to show me the image. Other browsers don't do that.

[Try this link.](http://freestocktextures.com/download/jpg/667)

How do I prevent Safari from launching Preview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the general pane of the preferences, uncheck the 'Open "safe" files after downloading'. I have mine unchecked and Safari doesn't open the file downloaded in your example link.

Comment: I missed that! That solves the problem! Thanks!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: How do you make Safari behave like other browsers and open the image in a browser window or tab, instead of using Preview?